# middle square method in hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am reading about middle square method in hashing at followiong location.

http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page212.html

Here author mentioned that keys which have a large number of leading zeroes will collide.

A similar line of reasoning applies for keys which have a large number of trailing zeroes.

Request to give an example and explanation what does author mean in above two statements.

Answer (score 0):

as the method says, the key `x` are being divided by `2^(w-k)`. at the bit level this actually means that the bits of `x` gets shifted by to the right by `(w-k)`.

now take a scenario where `x = 7`, `(w-k) = 3`. so `x = 00000111` and shifting  those bits to the right by `3` means `x = 00000000`.

now, u will notice that for all the values of `x` from `7 (00000111) to 0 (00000000)`, the bit shift would result in `00000000` (shifting bits to right always appends 0 to the left side). thus values that have large number of leading 0's (7 to 0) will collide to the same hash.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have question on above explanation x is divided by 2 ^ (w-k), I think we are right shift not left shift. Question is how author is exactrating middle digits, is how x*x >> (w-k) given middle digits

Comment: my mistake, bits are getting shifted to the right. that would end up appending 0`s to the left.
@venkysmarty

Comment: see. taking a different example. `x = 8 (00000100)` no dividing this by 2^(w-k) will give hash value `00000001`. from `x = 8`  we got `0001` that is the middle bits of `x`.
@venkysmarty

Comment: by the way what are values of w and k in above example

Comment: i have taken `w = 6, k = 3`